# add row and column titles with ggarrange

Tags: ggplot2, ggpubr

I have a list of ggplots that may be too complex to arrange using facet_wrap. All plots must share the same legend and should be arranged in a grid. Each column of the grid needs a different title, also each row of the grid needs a differen title.
An absurdly simple example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

plot1<- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=1, y=1, col="a"))
plot2<- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=1, y=1, col="a"))
plot3<- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=1, y=1, col="a"))
plot4<- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=1, y=1, col="a"))

plotlist<- list(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4)

ggarrange(plotlist = plotlist, ncol = 2, nrow = 2, common.legend = TRUE, legend="bottom")
```

This produces everything needed except the column and row titles, and annotate_figure only adds a global title to the figure. The desired output should look like:

[image: ggarrange with row and column titles]

Comment: small tip: you can also use `plot1<-plot2<-plot3<-plot4<-` when all objects are the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer the `patchwork` package. Controlling layout is easy. The titles are a bit tricky. Patchwork uses the labs from each plot - so you could add plot titles to the upper plots and maybe add a row to the y label in the left hand side plots.

Arguably easier is to create the titles as plot and add them to your patchwork. You can easily customise your layout like [explained in the patchwork vignette](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

plot1<-plot2<-plot3<-plot4<- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=1, y=1, col="a"))

row1 <- ggplot() + annotate(geom = 'text', x=1, y=1, label="row 1 title", angle = 90) + theme_void() 

row2 <- ggplot() + annotate(geom = 'text', x=1, y=1, label="row 2 title", angle = 90) + theme_void() 

col1 <- ggplot() + annotate(geom = 'text', x=1, y=1, label="col 1 title") + theme_void() 

col2 <- ggplot() + annotate(geom = 'text', x=1, y=1, label="col 2 title") + theme_void() 

layoutplot <- "
#cccddd
aeeefff
aeeefff
bggghhh
bggghhh
"

plotlist <- list(a = row1, b = row2, c = col1, d = col2, e= plot1, f=plot2, g=plot3, h=plot4)

wrap_plots(plotlist, guides = 'collect', design = layoutplot)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

I know it's late to reply, but for future searchers (including future me): The `ggpubr::annotate_figure` function is likely best here to reduce cross-package issues.

Reproducing:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

plot1<- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=1, y=1, col="a"))
plot2<- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=1, y=1, col="a"))
plot3<- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=1, y=1, col="a"))
plot4<- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=1, y=1, col="a"))

plotlist<- list(plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4)
```

Here is where you add it in:

```
commonplot <- ggarrange(plotlist = plotlist, ncol = 2, nrow = 2,
                        common.legend = TRUE, legend="bottom")

annotate_figure(commonplot, 
                top = "Column 1 Title                    Column 2 Title",
                left = "Row 2 Title                   Row 1 Title")
```

You can either assign the `ggarrange` object as an object, or you can pipe it down to `annotate_figure`.

The [documentation](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/annotate_figure.html) shows more functionality as well, like adding right and bottom labels and a common title.

[image: The display of the above code.]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since the question concerns `ggarrange` usage. It is a shame that there are no column and row titles in the `annotate_figure` function and the solution is so patchy.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add titles for subplots in the first row, i.e.,

```
plot1<- ggplot() + ggtitle("col title 1")
plot2<- ggplot() + ggtitle("col title 2")
```

This may compress the height of the plots in the first row as we have added a title. In `ggarrange`, you can use `heights()` to adjust the relative heights of each subplot then.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).